# Custom component , error compiling template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

What am I doing wrong here with my custom component?

What I want is to have:

- label
- input

Why is `idfor` undefined? Why do I get this error on `labeltext`

> invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in "Name of superhero"

`labeltext` is supposed to be a string and I should be able to pass in any string I like?

This is what I have so far. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/batcave/eywraw8t/258772/)

```
Vue.component("base-input", {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    idfor: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    labeltext: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: 
  `
  <div>
    <label for="idfor">{{labeltext}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="idfor" v-bind:value="value" v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
  </div>
  `
});

Vue.config.devtools = true;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        name: "Hulk",
        age: 42
      }
    };
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <base-input v-bind:idfor="name" v-bind:value="user.name" v-bind:labeltext="Name of superhero"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there's one problem, you just have to make sure you are including `''` for `literals`

```
<div id="app">
<base-input v-bind:idfor="'name'" v-bind:value="user.name" v-bind:labeltext="'Name of superhero'"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because `v-bind:labeltext=` evaluates the value as an expression. And if you need to pass an string then you need to wrap it in quotes like

```
v-bind:labeltext="'Name of superhero'"
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/258781/)